# Title and tags do not show up while editing a moderator edited question

Tags: bug, edits

The following post was edited by [a moderator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/50049/tim-post):

[How long can a temporary suspension be?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211217/how-long-can-a-temporary-suspension-be)

Attempting to edit the post opens it up without the title and the tags.  The revision history of the post can be accessed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/211217/revisions).

Surely one could copy/paste the title and add the tags while making the edit, but it seems like a bug.

(Needless to say this issue is not observed on other posts.)

Comment: That's because he hard deleted the first revision, there's a dupe, let me see...

Comment: Oh, and Tim Post is NOT just a moderator, he's a Community Manager.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Apologies.  _Community Manager and Chief Pun Officer for Stack Exchange_ is what the [profile](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/50049/tim-post) says.  I should have looked at it earlier.

Comment: Note that in my report the linked question was edited after my bug report thus it appears to be fine, but believe me it was empty before. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'll delete this in that event.

Comment: No need to delete, nothing wrong in having duplicates.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Invite a flurry of downvotes?

Comment: Why downvotes?? You didn't repeat it on purpose.