# Why were my comments pointing out an error in an answer deleted?

Tags: discussion, meta, deleted-comments

I have twice posted comments under an [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/338034/156890) by moderator [Tinkeringbell](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/369802/tinkeringbell) to the question [Under age users - could they just be suspended until of age?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/338033/156890)  These comments have pointed out that the answer contains an incorrect statement.  The comments have all been deleted.

For context, the incorrect statement concerns users in the EU who are under 16 years of age.  It is

> Basically SE is not allowed to keep any user data (including the e-mail address you use for signing up and registering your account)

The statement is incorrect because, as noted in the [document](https://www.betterinternetforkids.eu/en_US/web/portal/practice/awareness/detail?articleId=3017751) linked in [another answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/338035/156890), EU law actually allows each EU country to set the relevant age in its own national law anywhere from 13 to 16, and specifies that if any country fails to do so that the age will be 16 for that country.  The document also shows that the minimum age is currently 13 in eight EU countries, 14 in six, and 15 in three.

It appears to me that the moderator in question, or some other moderator, is using moderation tools to perpetuate disingenuous propaganda on this site and that Stack Exchange is falsely hiding behind a legal requirement that they have either misinterpreted or misrepresented willfully.

This is not a very charitable way of looking at the deletion of my comments, but I cannot think of any other reason for their deletion.  This does not comport with the [page describing moderation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators), which says that moderators are expected to be patient and fair, to lead by example, and to show respect for their fellow community members.

Answer (score 11):

Comments are not, and never have been meant to be permanent artifacts. They're transient.

The comments didn't particularly help to  clarify the answer, which focused basically on SE's reasoning as was given, rather than on the deep specifics of law. These are the rules *the company has set* taking into account the laws, or some subset of them in the countries they are operating in

They were deleted repeatedly because they were posted repeatedly.

You might want to instead consider distilling the points you were trying to make into an answer, or even a question.