# Some posts of mine weren't re-associated to my new account after it was mistakenly deleted

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, moderator-tools, user-accounts, deleted-accounts

Long story short, my old account was mistakenly deleted when I was 14 for being underage because I created my SO account when I was 12. This isn't allowed, because the minimum age is 13, but my account [should not have been deleted after I already turned 13](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/361023/377214); rather, this was due to a misunderstanding because I was talking about it in chat and a staff member thought that I was still underage at the time, even though I was a week off of turning 15.

After contacting SE support, they were very helpful and were able to merge (almost) all of my old content - answers, questions, and comments - into my current account, reassociating all of my data.

However, a few of my posts weren't re-associated properly. I only noticed 25 posts on CGCC.SE meta (none on the main site), and I'm not sure about other sites (I looked through the deleted account's posts on CGCC).

I don't exactly care about these posts (my old user ID is 42649 on CGCC, if this can be fixed), since they were all on meta, and all so old that nobody remembers them anymore, but I am just bringing this up as a bug report in case there's an issue that can be fixed for future uses of account re-association (which, and I'm not sure about this, probably is a pretty rarely used mechanism).

Comment: [Post from a staff member](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/351103/377214) that states that it's rare, but that the team *does* re-associate posts to new accounts if an underage user with lots of content comes back once they are of age.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no bug here. There is no tool for re-associating all content that was ever attached to every profile attached to a network account. We can only reattach posts on a per-site basis, one at a time, manually. And per-site also means Meta is a separate site as well.

You were likely asked which sites you wanted reassociated if there were multiple sites involved, as we would have wanted to minimize the amount of work we needed to do. If you don't care about the Meta posts, you likely didn't care about them at that time either and so nobody ran the process on Meta.

Ultimately, the user has to be specific about what all they want re-associated. The underage user deletion process wipes out all personal information and **it is not possible for us to track down these posts on our own in any way** as all evidence that you were attached to that previous account is gone forever. There has to be some sort of manual history record kept by the user, which is why we provide users a link to their profile when the deletion occurs

Comment: Ah, that must've been what happened. I _thought_ there were at least a few meta posts that did get re-associated, which is why I thought it wasn't behaving consistently, but I must be remembering incorrectly in that case. Thanks!