# Allow moderators to forgive review suspensions

Tags: feature-request, review, moderator-tools, review-suspension

Following up on [applying permanent review suspensions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/362709), I noticed several permabanned<sup>*</sup> users are suitable/eligible for review unsuspension due to the review suspension system overhaul (in particular - the review suspension message/reason is displayed to the user even if the suspension has expired).

However, I would also like to reduce/reset the suspension duration back to 4 (or a custom number of) days, because if I only lifted the review suspension, the next time the user hits an automated review audit suspension without me resetting the duration, they will encounter a doubled (730) or halved (183) suspension duration, which may be unfair to the reviewer under the updated system.

The act of "resetting the duration" not only applies to permabanned reviewers, and could also apply to reviewers with a long suspension duration whom we may wish to forgive in the future.

To achieve this, I would have to:

- Review-unsuspend the user
- Apply a new review suspension (with the shorter duration)
- Review-unsuspend the user again

This is not practical as the user will see a review suspension notice in the inbox and review queue pages, and may possibly be confused.

I would like an option in the moderator tools to be able to unsuspend the user, as well as, set/reset a new suspension duration without suspending the user in the process.

---

<sub>* **permabanned** reviewers have a specific meaning - one that is no longer welcome to perform reviews on a site, where a moderator applies a manual review suspension with the maximum number of days that the system allows (365 days)</sub>

Comment: Human intervention would better fit with the GDPR, in which people have the right to refuse [automated processing of data](https://ico.org.uk/for-organisations/guide-to-data-protection/guide-to-the-general-data-protection-regulation-gdpr/individual-rights/rights-related-to-automated-decision-making-including-profiling/) which requires explicit consent otherwise.

Comment: @ARogueAnt.Explicit consent is only required when the automated decision "...produces legal effects concerning him or her or similarly significantly affects him or her”, which is further expanded upon in the page you linked as "A legal effect is something that affects someone’s legal rights. Similarly significant effects are more difficult to define but would include, for example, automatic refusal of an online credit application, and e-recruiting practices without human intervention." I have a hard time seeing a review ban as sufficiently "significant" as to qualify under that wording.

Comment: You're probably right.  As far as I can tell, the world is still wrestling with the details and how to best to apply them and in what circumstances. Personally I'd err on the safe side where possible and have humans involved at most stages to avoid unnecessary "automated-injustice" until we've a  more advanced and stable internet/data-regulation approach. @Makyen

Comment: TBH this would be more in line with say clearing spam flags than bringing in messy things like GDPR.